# Click on Jquery Dialog UI button with Selenium using PhpUnit (PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, selenium, phpunit

I am working on an application using jquery Dialog UI.

We have a screen with this behaviour : if differents rules matched there are one or several Jquery UI dialog box chained after clicking on a form submit button.

With Phpunit SeleniumTestCase (see extension PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase) and Selenium RC I am trying to click on buttons of those Dialog box to simulate a test.

Unfortunately it doesn't work, I cannot use XPath because the number of Dialog Box are different and the Xpath of each will be different (matching the display rules). So i decided to set ID on buttons for example a typical UI dialog we are using :

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="position: absolute; height: auto; width: 300px; top: 343px; left: 487px; display: block;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-describedby="ui-id-10" aria-labelledby="ui-id-11">
   <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
      <span id="ui-id-11" class="ui-dialog-title">Attention</span>
      <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close">
         <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"/>
         <span class="ui-button-text">close</span>
      </button>
   </div>
   <div id="ui-id-10" style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 88px; max-height: none; height: auto;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">Le champ n° de secours n'a pas été renseigné; acceptez-vous qu'il soit affecté par défaut avec la valeur du ND cible?</div>
   <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
      <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
         <button type="button" id="popup_numero_secours_yes" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
            <span class="ui-button-text">Oui</span>
         </button>
         <button type="button" id="popup_numero_secours_no" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
            <span class="ui-button-text">Non</span>
         </button>
         <button type="button" id="popup_numero_secours_cancel" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
            <span class="ui-button-text">Annuler</span>
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: 90;"/>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"/>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"/>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 90;"/>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"/>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 90;"/>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 90;"/>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 90;"/>
</div>
```

But Selenium cannot catch any button identified with this id by doing :

```
$this->getXpathCount("//button[@id=\"popup_checklist_yes\"]");
```

or even using button label (what i don't like because not accurate) :

```
$this->getXpathCount("//button[@type=\"button\"]/span[text()=\"Oui\"]");
```

and this is not working too :

```
$this->click('id=popup_checklist_yes');
```

Anyone has encountered this problem and already fixed it ?

Thank you in advance !